# Hibernate+Spring framework project mapping error(exception)

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, hibernate-mapping

Caused by:

> org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: controler.Role, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(ROLE)]

Can you please help me on this?

this is my mapping class

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping>
  <class name="controler.Role" table="ROLE">
      <id name="roleId" column="ROLEID">
          <generator class="increment"/>
      </id>
      <property name="title" column="TITLE"/>
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

the Role is a pojo class and i have the relevant table named Role in the JavaDB. The role table has attributes roleid(char) and roletitle(varchar)

Answer (score 3):

> Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: controler.Role, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(ROLE)]

My initial assumption was wrong. But now that you mentioned JavaDB, I suspect that `ROLE` is actually [a reserved keyword](http://www.petefreitag.com/tools/sql_reserved_words_checker/?word=role). Try to enclose the table name in backticks in the mapping document:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping>
  <class name="controler.Role" table="`ROLE`">
      <id name="roleId" column="ROLEID">
          <generator class="increment"/>
      </id>
      <property name="title" column="TITLE"/>
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

#### References

- Hibernate reference guide

  - [5.4. SQL quoted identifiers](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/reference/en/html/mapping.html#mapping-quotedidentifiers)

Comment: The Role is actually a table in the Java DB. i have a pojo class named "Role" and the Role table has "roleid"(char) and "roletitle"(varchar).

Comment: This is my mapping class  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping>
  <class name="controler.Role" table="ROLE">
      <id name="roleId" column="ROLEID">
          <generator class="increment"/>
      </id>
      <property name="title" column="TITLE"/>
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>

Comment: @hasitha Edit your question (there is an edit link at the bottom) to post your POJOs and mappings.

Comment: @hasitha: If you indent your XML with Ctrl-K, it'll show up in the text

Comment: @Pascal Thivent Unfortunately I could not see your responses about Scrum / Agile. I hope I have some spare time this week. Anyway, UP

Comment: @Arthur Thanks. Regarding my Scrum/Agile answers, no problem, I'm not going to remove them anyway ;)

Answer (score 0):

Is the fully-qualified name of the Java class actually `controler.Role`? What does the source code of the `Role` class look like? Is it in a package named `controler`?

Perhaps the name is simply misspelt.

Answer (score 0):

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping>
  <class name="controler.Role" table="`ROLE`">
      <id name="roleId" type="int" column="ROLEID">
          <generator class="increment"/>
      </id>
      <property name="title" column="TITLE"/>
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>`